# speed up DOM access while using $element.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, performance

I'm trying to make some serious delay cuts in my hefty javascript UI application.
I've been reading up ways to optimize code, and from a few things that I've learnt, I understand that:

1. $(element).each() makes things slower
2. Variables (and HTML Objects) should be cached

This is part of my existing code within a function that runs quite often in my application:

```
if($('.textbox').length > 0)
{   $(".textbox").each(function(){
             var parts = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
             // do some linear-time operations here with $this
            });
     });
```

So far, I know I should put `$this = $(this)` at the beginning of the `.each()` and only use `$(this)`. But what else can I do? Is there any quicker, substitute way to use .each()?  I do need to check out *each* `div` with the `.textbox` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what else can I do?

Several things:

1. There is absolutely no point to your `if` statement (unless it has an `else` clause you haven't shown), since calling `.each` on an empty jQuery object is a no-op. Remove it.
2. If you don't want to remove it, at least cache the result of the DOM lookup, as each time you call `$('.textbox')` jQuery has to go off and query the DOM.
3. `id` is a reflected property on DOM element instances, so `$(this).attr("id").split('_')` involves multiple function calls and memory allocations you can avoid by using `this.id.split('_')`.

So that gives us:

```
$('.textbox').each(function() {
    var parts = this.id.split('_');
    // Do something with `parts`
});
```

Or if there was an `else` you haven't shown:

```
var boxes = $('.textbox');
if (boxes.length) {
    boxes.each(function() {
        var part s= this.id.split('_');
        // ...
    });
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'm a little confused about the way you're using `this` directly. Is that more efficient than using `$this`? Can we use `this` directly even for things like `$this.css('left')`?

Comment: @user961627: Within `each` (and within jQuery event handlers), `this` refers to the raw DOM element, meaning you can use any properties or methods that DOM elements have (see [the various DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)). When you do `$(this)`, you're calling jQuery and passing in the DOM element, and getting back a jQuery wrapper around it. That wrapper provides the jQuery functions like `css` and such.

Comment: Thanks - I've been confused about that wrapper part for ages - you put the words very clearly.

Comment: So what's the difference in terms of efficiency, in getting a jQuery wrapper and using `$(this).css`, or accessing CSS properties directly from `this`? I'm assuming the not calling the wrapper will be better? Or is it almost negligible again?

Comment: @user961627: Negligible, but again, if you're doing it a *lot*, sometimes (*sometimes*) negligible can add up. But note that jQuery (and libraries like it) do a *lot* under the covers to simplify things for you and smooth over browser differences.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery which executes a lot of codes in behind. The fastest way is native Javascript.

A real small optimalisation is get the `id` from `this`. You could also use this (Native JS) jQuery would execute a lot of functions):

```
var parts = this.id.split('_');
```

**So for example**
Getting all elements as fast as possible. You could use this function to get an element by class name:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
    {
        var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var results = [];

        var element;
        for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
            var elementClass = element.className;
            if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                results.push(element);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

And the code to loop:

```
var elements = getElementsByClassName(".textbox");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
{
    var splitid = elements[i].id.split("_");
}
```

Comment: if I'm using pure javascript, would I still need to use `getElementsByClassName(".textbox");`, or would we get rid of the dot `.` before the class name? Also, just wondering - don't most browsers already have `document.getElementsByClassName` defined?

Comment: @user961627: You'd get rid of the dot (but you'd also have the issue that not all browsers have `getElementsByClassName`, although all modern ones do). But it's a **massive** over-generalization to say that using "pure JavaScript" is "faster" than using a library. In the vast majority of cases, there is no measurable difference provided you're using the library correctly (for instance, by not querying the DOM twice in a row for the same information, which will naturally be slower than just doing it once regardless of how you do it).

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder that is exacly what I meant, jQuery is really nice to do things easy. But if you want performance you probably don't want the all the library overhead.